# Overwrite JQuery css values with Css MediaQueries

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries

I am building a sort-of responsive web layout using css media queries. 
I just started including some animations with jQuery and ran into the following problem:

When animating elements with jQuery, each element receives the animated values in their `style="..."` property. That means their original values, which may have been stored in a class, are ignored. I have a media query which targets `print` and resets the animated values to provide a better visual experience on paper. The issue is, that the changes in the media queries do not affect the element, since they now have their own style property which is stronger than the class settings.

```
@media print{
    .PaddOnScroll{
        padding-left: 1.6em;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="ContentBounds TitleFont PaddOnScroll" style="padding-left: 0px; opacity: 0;">
    ...
</div>
```

Do you have an idea of how I can force my media queries to be applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to override an inline rule via css is using **!important**.

```
@media print{
    .PaddOnScroll{
        padding-left: 1.6em !important;
        opacity: 1 !important;
    }
}
```

Another solution using jquery only is to [count screen size](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and apply rule with [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Comment: Omg, I use !important a couple times on my page but I didn't though about it at all in this case! Thank you. Will accept in 11 minutes...