# Why doesn't this Media Query overrules the main CSS

Tags: html, css

I have no idea, why doesn't this media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px){

    .hero-text-box {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 2%; 
    }   
}
```

doesn't overrules the standard style css witch looks like this

```
.hero-text-box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1140px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

When I look at google chrome developer tool when the screen size is under 1200px, the padding works, but not the 100% width. IT is just crossed over.

Comment: Does it work if you add !important to the property?

Comment: can you show this in fiddle??

Comment: Check the answer on a question I asked a couple months back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28580933/overwrite-jquery-css-values-with-css-mediaqueries

Comment: @noelwidmer It worked thanks. :) Do you know why it worked? and why didn't it work on the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing is the order that these rules appear in your CSS. You should put the media query rules below the regular rules:

```
.hero-text-box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1140px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px){
    .hero-text-box {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 2%; 
    }   
}
```

If these rules are in separate files, make sure you include the file with the media query after the file with the regular styles.

Comment: Thanks I'm still strugling with the file order, yes it was in different file and now that I added it after the main style.css it works without the !important.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to put the media query rule after the general rule.

```
.hero-text-box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1140px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px){
    .hero-text-box {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 2%; 
    }   
}
```